# what is the most effective way to find the modal values of a list?

Tags: python, algorithm

to be able to work with bimodal lists etc.

my attempts so far:

```
testlist = [1,2,3,3,2,1,4,2,2,3,4,3,3,4,5,3,2,4,55,6,7,4,3,45,543,4,53,4,53,234]
```

.

```
from collections import Counter

def modal_1(xs):
    cntr = Counter(xs).most_common()
    val,count = cntr[0]
    return (v for v,c in cntr if c is count)

print(list(modal_1(testlist)))
>>> [3, 4]
```

-- or perhaps something like --

```
def modal_2(xs):
       cntr = Counter(xs).most_common()
       val,count = cntr[0]
       return takewhile(lambda x: x[1] is count, cntr)

print(list(modal_2(testlist)))
>>> [(3, 7), (4, 7)]
```

Please do not answer - use numpy etc.

note :

`Counter(xs).most_common(1)`

returns the first 'modal' of n modal values. If there are two. It will only return the first. Which is a shame... because that would make this a whole lot easier.

---

ok, so I was actually quite surprised that one of my original options is actually a good way to do this. for anyone now wanting to find n modal numbers in a list, I would suggest the following options. Both of these functions work well on lists with over 1000 values

All of these return lists of (number,count), where count will be identical for all tuples. I think it is better to have this and then parse it to your hearts desire.

using takewhile:

```
from collections import Counter
from itertools import takewhile

def modal_3(xs):
    counter = Counter(xs).most_common()
    mx = counter[0][1]
    return takewhile(lambda x: x[1] == mx, counter)

print(list(modal_3(testlist)))
>>> [(3, 7), (4, 7)]
```

using groupby:

```
from collections import Counter
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter

def modal_4(xs):    
    container = Counter(xs)
    return next(groupby(container.most_common(), key=itemgetter(1)))[1]

print(list(modal_4(testlist)))
>>> [(3, 7), (4, 7)]
```

and the final, pythonic, and fastest way:

```
def modal_5(xs):

    def _mode(xs):
        for x in xs:
            if x[1] != xs[0][1]:
                break
            yield x

    counter = collections.Counter(xs).most_common()

    return [ x for x in _mode(counter) ]
```

thank you to everyone for the help and information.

Comment: That is a lot of ellipsis. Periods need love too.

Comment: I thought it made the question more ... open.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not seeing why `Counter.most_common(1)` doesn't do it for you?

Comment: because it only seems to return the first value, but if there are two matches it will not give the second! unless I am being completely ...

Comment: @ThemanontheClaphamomnibus Indeed, You are right, I had it in my head it worked the other way. I think your `takewhile` solution is the most elegant it is going to get, to be honest.

Comment: `mx = counter.most_common(1)[0][1]` could have better time complexity depending on the implementation of `Counter`.

Comment: @PeterGraham +1 I have updated to include this. although as `most_common(1)` is the first element of `most_common()` I have slightly adapted it. It makes the code cleaner I think - no excess variables for no reason!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your second example is best, with some minor modification:

```
from itertools import takewhile
from collections import Counter

def modal(xs):
       counter = Counter(xs).most_common()
       _, count = counter[0]
       return takewhile(lambda x: x[1] == count, counter)
```

The change here is to use `==` rather than `is` - `is` checks for identity, which while true for some values as Python does some magic with `int`s in the background to cache them, won't be true all of the time, and shouldn't be relied upon in this case.

```
>>> a = 1
>>> a is 1
True
>>> a = 300
>>> a is 300
False
```

Comment: I actually changed the code to is, as I I thought people would complain about `==` Oh well ;)

Comment: `is` should pretty much only be used when checking for identity, and the only common time you want to do that is against `None`.

Comment: ah yes! that sounds familiar.

Comment: I had actually tried this but got: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mode2.py", line 72, in <module>
    print(list(m3))
  File "mode2.py", line 29, in <lambda>
    return takewhile(lambda x: x[1] == mx, counter) 
TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable
`

Comment: its because counter is a dict like object not a list

Comment: @ThemanontheClaphamomnibus The edits broke it, I just reverted it to a working version. I was trying to remove the `most_common()` call as suggested above, but then `takewhile()` won't work as they won't be in order.

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> testlist = [1,2,3,3,2,1,4,2,2,3,4,3,3,4,5,3,2,4,55,6,7,4,3,45,543,4,53,4,53,234]
>>> dic={x:testlist.count(x) for x in set(testlist)}

>>> [x for x in dic if dic[x]==max(dic.values())]

[3, 4]
```

Comment: -1 - I see no reason to reimplement `collections.Counter()` with something far less efficient here.

Comment: @Lattyware: Agree, but `max(cntr.values())` (on a Counter) would work as well, and that does seem more elegant than `val,count = cntr[0]`

Comment: @Junuxx Not really, as Counter will give us ordered results, if we do `max()` we  are searching through the list again for no reason.

Comment: @Lattyware: `cntr.most_common()` gives ordered results, but sorting all the results is more than what is necessary if you just want the max. You could leave out the call to most_common and use max instead?

Comment: values can not be called on `Counter.most_common` it has to be called on `Counter(xs).values()`

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean. The issue there is that `max()` will only return one value, so in that case, you might as well just call `Counter.most_common(1)` - but the asker wants all the max values.

Comment: @Lattyware run this on your system, http://ideone.com/ZQlhx.
EDIT: run this http://ideone.com/f5JrO

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary This is a relatively small data set - it should be run on a larger one, and also, your are not comparing to the solution given in my answer, using `takewhile()`.

Comment: @Lattyware even your solution is taking twice time than my solution. o.O

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary, this is a nice solution!

Comment: -- edit, for SMALL lists, the tests that I have just done with random numbers and a list of len(100) put it at about 3 X slower than the original take while function

Comment: seriously, this is slow on big lists!

Comment: It was always going to be slower as it does `list.count()` for every item in the list, which means it has to go over the entire list once for every unique item. The `Counter()` goes over the list once, by comparison.

Answer (score 2):

What? `takewhile` but no `groupby`?

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> testlist = [1,2,3,3,2,1,4,2,2,3,4,3,3,4,5,3,2,4,55,6,7,4,3,45,543,4,53,4,53,234]
>>> cntr = Counter(testlist)
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> list(x[0] for x in next(groupby(cntr.most_common(), key=lambda x:x[1]))[1])
[3, 4]
```

Comment: so this means that as soon as the key changes, the list is complete? `It generates a break or new group every time the value of the key function changes`

Comment: almost as fast as takewhile :)

Comment: Try changing the key function to `itemgetter(1)` so that groupby never has to leave C code to call out to Python.

Comment: Also, this solution strips off the counts, and just returns the modal values. Change to `list(next(groupby(cntr.most_common(), key=operator.itemgetter(1)))[1])` for comparable work and return values.